# How to display fragment at activity start up

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity with button's. On press they display different fragment. But on activity start, FrameLayout(which used to display fragments) is empty/blank. How can i make it to display `news_ru` fragment at activity startup?

Here is my code for fragment display:

```
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                replaceFragment(new news_ru());
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                replaceFragment(new news_kz());
            }
        });

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.newsFL, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your `private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment)` method inside onCreate of Activity after initialzing `new xyzFragment()` in your case it would be like

```
replaceFragment(new news_ru());
```